# Need to cover test class with 75 %

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

[image]Don't know why i am facing this issues in my test class to cover up the coverage with 75 %.

I am getting only 18 % code coverage.

Class :

```
global class SendPurchaseOrdrService{
    webService static String sendMail(String orderID) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        try{
            Map<String,Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c> emailsetting = Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c.getAll();
            List<Purchase_Order__c> orderlst = [Select id,Opportunity__r.Accountid,Opportunity__r.Account.Name,Total_Amount__c,CurrencyIsoCode,Name,Type__c,Purchase_Order_Email_Sent__c from Purchase_Order__c where id =: orderID];
            String emailAddress = orderlst.size()>0 ? emailsetting.get(orderlst[0].Type__c).Email__c : null;
            if(emailAddress != null && emailAddress.length()>0){ 
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();        
                Pagereference pg = Page.PrintPurchaseOrder;
                pg.getParameters().put('id', orderID);
                Blob fileBody = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('test') : pg.getcontentasPDF();

                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attachment.setBody(fileBody);                
                attachment.setFileName('Purchase_Order.pdf');               
                mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );  

                mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>{emailAddress});

                mail.setSubject('The Shaker Kitchen Company Purchase Order');

                String body = 'Dear Sir / Madam, <br/><br/>';
                body += 'Our Purchase Order for your products is attached, please acknowledge receipt of this order via return email and quote the PO number on all invoices and correspondance.<br/><br/>';
                body += 'If you have any queries, please call 01285 238070 or email finance@theshakerkitchencompany.com <br/><br/>';
                body += 'Kind regards, <br/><br/>';
                body += 'The Shaker Kitchen Company <br/><br/>';
                mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                mails.add(mail);
            }           



            if(mails.size()>0){
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            }


            Task task = new Task();
            task.Customer_Name__c = orderlst.get(0).Opportunity__r.Accountid;
            task.Total_Amount__c= orderlst.get(0).Total_Amount__c;
            task.WhatId = orderlst.get(0).Opportunity__c;
            task.Opportunity__c = orderlst.get(0).Opportunity__c;
            task.ActivityDate = system.today();
            task.Subject = orderlst.get(0).Name;
            task.Status = 'Completed';
            task.Priority ='Normal';
            task.CurrencyIsoCode = orderlst.get(0).CurrencyIsoCode;
            insert task;

            for(Purchase_Order__c purOrder : orderlst){
                purOrder.Purchase_Order_Email_Sent__c = true;
            }
            system.debug('@@orderlst : '+ orderlst);
            update orderlst;
            return 'send'; 
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('ex==>'+ex.getmessage());
            return ex.getmessage();
        }
     return null;
   }  
}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class SendPurchaseOrdrServiceTest{
    static testMethod void MyTest(){
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'test';
        a.Email__c = 'test@test.com';
        a.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
        a.Phone = '789642';
        a.BillingCity= 'bhuj';
        a.BillingPostalCode = '370001';
        a.BillingCountry = 'india';
        a.BillingLatitude = 57.5 ;
        a.BillingLongitude = 67.7;
        a.BillingState = 'Gujarat';
        a.BillingStreet = 'Main';
        insert a;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        opp.StageName = 'Stage 0';
        opp.CloseDate = system.today().addDays(10);
        opp.Accountid = a.id;
        opp.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        insert opp;

        Purchase_Order__c po = new Purchase_Order__c();
        po.Name = 'test';
        po.Opportunity__c = opp.id;
        po.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        po.Purchase_Order_Email_Sent__c = true;
        po.Type__c = 'NEFF';
        insert po;

        Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Test Data');  
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName( quote.Name + '.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b); 

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();  
        attachment.ParentId = a.id;  
        attachment.Name = 'Test Attachment for Parent';  
        attachment.Body = b;  
        insert(attachment);

        List<Attachment> attachments = [select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=: a.Id];
        System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());

        Task task = new Task();
        task.Customer_Name__c = a.id;
        task.Total_Amount__c = 12000;
        task.WhatId = opp.id;
        task.Opportunity__c = opp.id;
        task.ActivityDate = system.today();
        task.Subject = 'Invoice ';
        task.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        task.Status = 'Completed';
        task.Priority ='Normal';
        insert task;

        Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',po.Id);
        SendPurchaseOrdrService.sendMail(po.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `sendMail` method is throwing an exception at the following line:

```
String emailAddress = orderlst.size()>0 ?
       emailsetting.get(orderlst[0].Type__c).Email__c : null;
```

I think that the `orderlst` query is returning records, so it must be this line:

```
Map<String,Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c> emailsetting = Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c.getAll();
```

It is probably returning an empty map, which means that you don't have anything in your email settings, so you need to insert some records to it as well in your test class.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with this line where I believe `Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c` is a custom setting.

```
Map<String,Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c> emailsetting = Purchase_Order_Email_Receiver__c.getAll();
```

You need to insert records for the custom settings as well. 
You can also try loading the test data from a csv file and use `Test.loadData`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm